# Collision method gone crazy;

Tags: java, collision-detection, lwjgl

I am building a 2d tile based game, similiar to a Legend of Zelda game, and my collision method is not working properly.  The method will return collisions when the player is far below an impassable tile.  There must be a logic error I do not see here.  This is in Java.

From static collision class:

```
public static boolean collisionAbovePlayer(TileGrid grid, float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    boolean collision = false;

    for (Tile[] row : grid.map) {
        for (Tile t : row) {

            // Each Tile t in map:

            if (t.getType().getPassable() == false) {

                // Each impassable tile:

                if (  (x-t.getX() > 0 &&  x - t.getX() < t.getWidth()) || (x - t.getX() < 0 && Math.abs(x - t.getX()) < width )) {

                    // Tile is within collision x range

                    if ((t.getY() + t.getHeight() + 1) - y < Math.abs(5)) {
                        collision = true;
                    } else {
                        collision = false;
                    }

                } else {
                    collision = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return collision;
}
```

This is being called by this method in my Player class (I haven't implemented collision methods for the other directions yet):

```
public void Update() {
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else {
        if ((Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) && (!collisionAbovePlayer(grid, x, y, width, height))) {
            y -= Delta() * speed;
        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            x -= Delta() * speed;
        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
            y += Delta() * speed;
        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
            x += Delta() * speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need to see more of the code, thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in your debugger?

Comment: Just three small comments: `if (t.getType().getPassable() == false)` use this instead `if (!t.getType().getPassable())`. `Math.abs(5)` .. isn't it the same as `5`? And the last: don't do this: `collision = true;`. You're detecting a collision and saving it to the variable. Then you're continuing the iteration through you loops and if other tiles don't collide with the player, the variable `collision` will be overriden with `false`. If you detect a collision do `return true;` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I don't remember what I was doing with 'Math.abs(5)' but i originally had it set to 1, so it would return true if the impassable tile was one pixel above, but I was worried the player sprite might skip over it if the 'Delta()' was too high.

Comment: Ah, it continues to cycle to the last tile and returns that one.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
public static boolean collisionAbovePlayer(TileGrid grid, float x, float y, int width, int height) {

    for (Tile[] row : grid.map) {
        for (Tile t : row) {

            // Each Tile t in map:

            if (!t.getType().getPassable()) {

                // Each impassable tile:

                if ((x - t.getX() > 0 &&  x - t.getX() < t.getWidth()) || (x - t.getX() < 0 && Math.abs(x - t.getX()) < width )) {

                    // Tile is within collision x range

                    System.out.println("IN X RANGE");

                    if (Math.abs((t.getY() + t.getHeight() + 1) - y) < 2) {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In the original code it only returned the last tile that set 'boolean collision' to true, and the final statement checking the Y required Math.abs() around the first value.